# Select object in image using OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I need to select an object from a image using OpenCV. Object is different color than background of an image.

For example http://i.imgur.com/6pCCzwQ.jpg

How can i select only bowl ?

Comment: Please post sample code to show that you've tried working on it yourself before asking people to write your code for you

Answer (score 1):

in this case simple color detection will do. if you are not satisfied with the results you can try a thresholding the image, and then finding the contours from it (and of-course filtering them, mostly based area or get the outer contours ). or you could also use an edge detector (canny for example).